# .Net Core API - Mixed Model Binding not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, core-api

**Framework used is .Net Core 3.0 but tested in 2.2 and got the same behavior.**

I am using a class to automatically bind the body request properties and that works pretty well, even without having the [FromBody] attribute on them.

Now, I added a new property in this class that will match a property from the header and it works if I use it directly into the controller, like this:

```cs
public IActionResult Test(TestRequest request, [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] string token)
```

However, when I try to get the same result by adding the [FromHeader] attribute into the class property, it doesn't work.

Here is a sample code to illustrate the issue:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IActionResult Test(TestRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("request.UserId: " + request.UserId);
        Console.WriteLine("request.Token: " + request.Token);
        return Ok();
    }
}
public class TestRequest
{
    [FromBody]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Did anybody ever face the same issue?

Comment: Can you clear up the confusion, you say *added a new property in this class that will match a property from the header and it works if I use it directly into the controller, like this* and then say *I try to get the same result by adding the [FromHeader] attribute into the class property, it doesn't work.* - **but in both cases you show the same code**

Comment: Did you try removing `[FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")] string token`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson sure, the full code contains both approaches, using the FromHeader attribute into the controller and also in the class. This way you can see the one which works (controller) and the one which does not (class). Look at the image I posted to see the results, please!

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, Actually as I just mentioned to Jeremy, this is the full code containing both approaches. I tried using just one of them and both of them, but only the controller one works.

Comment: @LeandroBremer have you had a chance to review Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: @Nkosi yes, I did. It says can be used like this (in the class property), but unfortunately does not work. =/

Comment: @LeandroBremer can you point me to the place in the MSDN reference where it says it can be used like this (a class property)?

Comment: @JeremyThompson this sentence: "Are added to model properties individually (not to the model class), as in the following example"  [FromQuery(Name ="Note")]

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure `SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters` as true in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs like below :

```
services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
        });
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Test(TestRequest request)
```

And call the api with your `Authorization` header(not shown below) and body string, for postman
[image]

**Update:**

Since you use `[FromBody]` on the string property,it accepts a string instead of json object.

If you still would like to pass json object as `{ "userId" : "123" }`, you could warp the userId into a model,for example:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
public class TestRequest
{
    [FromBody]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [FromHeader(Name = "Authorization")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that worked!!! However, my Json request stopped working. I got a Bad Request and needed to change the body request format excluding the brackets and the parameter name... from this  `{ "userId" : "123"  }`  to this `"123"`    ...=/ ...
Do you know if there is a way to keep the same format working? I am using .Net Core 3.0

Comment: @Leandro Bremer That is because you add `[FromBody]` on the property,so you need to pass a string instead of an object.Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11699

Comment: @Leandro Bremer  if you want to pass it as an objectm then you need to wrap userId into a viewmodel.See my update.

Comment: @Leandro Bremer Could you accept the answer if you have resolved the problem?Thank you!

Comment: That worked properly!! I'll have to change my code here, however, it's gonna be really structured!!  Thank you, man!